# creating triggers with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

Two tables: users and messages

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`verifystring` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`usertype` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`img` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
`id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date` datetime NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`subject` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`body` text NOT NULL,
`img` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `topic_id` (`topic_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=51 ;
```

trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `updateimg` AFTER UPDATE ON `users`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
    update messages set img = new.img where messages.user_id = users.id;
end
```

img field is keeping the name of the image user has uploaded. 
How can i copy the value img from table users to table messages when it is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats should do it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update AFTER UPDATE ON table1
    for each ROW
    begin
        update table2 set y = new.y where table2.user_id = new.id;
    end
```

Comment: the trigger is being created but it doesn't work.
Why it doesn't allow me to specify UPDATE ON table.y?

Comment: do you get an error? what do you mean by your question?

Comment: No error but the values are not updated. 

I mean i want the trigger to be executed only when value of Y in table 1 is updated. So why it doesn't allow UPDATE ON Table1.y?

Comment: I just updated the answer, it is now table2.id = new.id

Comment: Still not working, do you want me to update the question with screenshots of the database and the query after which i want the trigger to be activated?

Comment: are you sure table2.id has the same values as table1.id? is table1 a 1 to 1 correspondence with table2. You can add screenshots, maybe better the CREATE TABLE statements for table 1 and 2

Comment: I have made the changes, see them if you need any additional info please let me know. I am really stuck with this trigger.

Comment: I see, the trigger does not work because the id of table 1 has nothing to do with the id of table 2. what is the foreign key in messages that link to users? is it user_id?

Comment: There is no foreign key into messages that links to the users.

But probably i should put user_id to be foreign key.

Comment: you don't need to explictly declare it, although you should. I've adjusted the answer.

Comment: Yeah it was working without the foreign key but i just placed it there. This is for my project so it wont kill anyone if there is no Foreign key :p
Thank you for the answer. IT WORKS! :D